# Make 'NA' columns of a specific 'type' in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, na, tidyverse

I'm making a function to summarise columns within dplyr. Within groups defined by `group_by`: if the values in a column are some constant, k, the summarised value for that group should be `k`, but if the column is non-constant the value should be NA.

Ideally, I'd like to convert the NA to the class of the input column; so if it's a numeric column, the summary function returns the equivalent of `as(NA, "numeric")`.

To do the above I've written a function `.collapse_if_constant`; but for simplicity in this question I'd just like to work out how to make NA columns of a specified type within dplyr.

Let

```
DF <- data.frame(x = "A", y = 1:3, z = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

Then

```
DF %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(y = as(NA, class(y)), z = as(NA, class(z)))
```

returns

```
  x      y     z
  (fctr) (lgl) (lgl)
1 A       NA    NA
```

But, I want it to look like

```
tibble::tibble(x = factor("A"), y = as(NA, "numeric"), z = NA)
  x      y     z
  (fctr) (dbl) (lgl)
1 A       NA    NA
```

... so that the summarised columns are of the same class as the input columns.

---

Please disregard this question. I was using an earlier release of dplyr (v0.4.3; current is 0.7.4 on CRAN); the issue has been resolved.

Comment: `?NA` notes that you may use `NA_integer_`, `NA_real_`, `NA_complex_`, and `NA_character_`. for integer, numeric, complex, and character classes, respectively.

Comment: I know, but to dynamically construct an NA of a particular type I use `as(NA, type_name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `summarize_at` seems to preserve the type, for example :

```
DF %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise_at(c("y", "z"), funs(as(NA, class(.))))
```

Comment: ARG! Sorry i was using dplyr::0.4.3; summarise works fine in dplyr::0.7. Thanks for your help.